# How to declare an operator overloading < to dynamically shift between class variables whenever needed?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I've been searching lots of sites and browsed few books about this but failed to come across to find good sources about implementation of how to dynamically (within execution of the program) compare different datatypes in a class with **less- <** or , **bigger than >** operators.

Let's say we've the following snippet code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class OP
{
private:
    string alias;
    float locatorX;
    int coordinate;
public:
    bool operator<(const OP& rhs)
    {
        return (this->locatorX < rhs.locatorX);
        //Here! How do I do to make the compiler understand that
        //I compare i.e alias or coordinate whenever I need? 
        //I tried with:
            return (this->coordinate < rhs.coordinate, this->alias < rhs.alias);
        //But it didn't really do the trick when implemented 
        //a sort algorithm inside main as it failed to sort a string array.
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Since most of the kind people here did not understand the question, here is a scenario which you hopefully get.

Let us say we want to create a map that accepts a string, int and float types. We create a function inside of the class OP that accepts all given datatypes and saves them in the created class array. And so we have i.e 15 records in our class array.

How do I do so that I can dynamically bubble sort (with help of < operator), alias (string) locatorX(float) and coordinate(int) (whichever I choose) in ascending order with less than operator?

For example I somewhat need to sort coordinates or alias (if needed) at run time. How do I do this?

**Example output:**

**(First position in array):**

"Albert street 5th"

Coordinate: 1691

locatorX: 19.52165

**(Second position in array):**

"Main street 7th alley"

Coordinate: 59

locatorX: 8175. 12

**(Third position in array):**

"Elm/Kentucky"

Coordinate: 9517

locatorX: 271.41

Comment: Can we get usage examples with expected return values?

Comment: I would write a separate compare function for each member.

Comment: This'd probably be a good Programmers.SE, question, btw.

Comment: @CalCharlesFox Unless I am misunderstanding your comment, you can overload the `operator<` function and have: `bool operator<(const std::string &rhs)`, `bool operator<(int rhs)`, and `bool operator<(float rhs)` inside your class.

Comment: @ncalmbeblpaicr0011 I am aware of that.  The OP wants to be able to call `<` and have it compare a particular member.  The only way I know to do that is to write a separate compare function for each member.

Comment: @ncalmbeblpaicr0011: From the bubble sort comment, this comparator is going to be used for sorting, so it'll always be `bool operator<(const OP&, const OP&)`, but the OP wants to switch between comparators based on `$some_condition_he_refuses_to_specify`. The task is likely extremely simple, but without the requirements being properly explained, nobody can confidently recommend a solution (beyond the high-level ideas I provided in my answer 2 hours ago) so this entire enterprise is completely pointless.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be several ways to do so:

#### Switch between comparison functions at the call site

You have to define separate compare functions for different fields.

```
std::vector<Object> v;

enum class OrderBy
{
    alias,
    coordinate
}

OrderBy order_by = get_orderBy_from_user();

switch (order_by)
{
case OrderBy::alias:
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_by_alias());
    break;
case OrderBy::coordinate:
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_by_coordinate());
    break;
}
```

#### Make a choice inside a comparison function.

You must communicate the choice of ordering field somehow into the function. 
The options are: global or singleton "configuration" object, member variable in the comparison class. I would avoid any globals, thus the second option:

```
struct compare_by_field
{
    OrderBy order_by_;

    compare_by_field(OrderBy order_by) : order_by_(order_by)
    {}

    bool operator()(const Object & lhs, const Object & rhs) const
    {
        switch (order_by_)
        {
        case OrderBy::alias:
            return lhs.alias < rhs.alias;
        case OrderBy::coordinate:
            return lhs.coordinate < rhs.coordinate;
        }
    }
}

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), compare_by_field(get_order_by_from_user()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd create a separate comparator for each comparison you wish to implement. You can't munge them into a single `operator<` and, although you could technically produce a different function that performed a different comparison depending on the value of some new, third argument, it would be incompatible with almost everything currently existing that knows how to work with comparators.

This is one of the scenarios in which operator overloading specifically is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @CalCharlesFox: You can "operate" as many datatypes in a function as you want, but you can't return three values from a function that expects to return one, nor can I think of a single situation in which you'd even want, let alone need, to do so. Perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @CalCharlesFox: How should it know which you want it to use at any given time? It cannot read your mind!

Comment: @CalCharlesFox: Repeating the same words doesn't help. You seem to be expecting the program to perform magic, switching between members for comparison according to .... what? What are the requirements? What are the constraints? You still haven't really explained what you want the program to do. Perhaps some concrete examples would better serve this question.

Comment: @CalCharlesFox: It still just says you want to do something "dynamically", but it doesn't actually tell us what that thing is, or how your program should make the choice. If you can't tell _us_ how the computer should make the choice, then you can't tell the computer how it should make the choice, and that's why you're so far unable to design a solution.

Comment: @CalCharlesFox: No, I don't, and I keep explaining why that is, and prompting you to provide the missing information, but you still aren't doing so. Repeating the information we already have for a fourth time doesn't help me to discover the information that I'm asking for in order to help you solve your problem. So I'm bowing out. Good luck.

Comment: @CalCharlesFox: I'm not sure how you confused me wasting two hours of my evening repeatedly asking you for the missing information as "not even trying to understand the question". I even gave a high-level idea in my answer, which more than likely contains the solution you need. You're the one who hasn't even tried it. I strongly recommend being less combative when you're asking for free help in the future.